# How to send this table output as an email using SMTP - Python from a Linux server?

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to send this as an output using a Python script using SMTP details that I have from a Linux server but somehow, I am unsure how to expect an output in the email like this?

```
import win32com.client as win32
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
# TODO this is for quick and dirty testing, Need to make creds out side file and with svc acc
username=''  #add username
passwd=''  #add password.
# Making a get request
## http://development.789@abc.com:7180/api/v1/clusters/RBS%20PROD%20MM/services/hdfs/roles
base_urls=[
    {'name':'RBS PROD MM','url':'http://development.789@abc.com:7180/api/v1/clusters/RBS%20PROD%20MM/services/','nn_url': 'http://development.789@abc.com:9870/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=FSNamesystem'},
    {'name':'RBS PROD MG','url':'http://development.899@abc.com:7180/api/v1/clusters/RBS%20PROD%20MG/services/','nn_url': 'http://development.788@abc.com:9870/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=FSNamesystem'}
]
for burl in base_urls:
    print (burl['name'],burl['url'])
    base_url=burl['url']
    response = requests.get(base_url,
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, passwd))
    status=[]
    for i in response.json()['items']:
        response_2 = requests.get(base_url+i['name'],
                    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, passwd))
        for j in response_2.json()['healthChecks']:
            status.append([i['name'],j['name'],j['summary']])
    tab='''<style>
            table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            </style>
            <br><br>
            <table><tr style="background-color: #858483"><th>Component</th><th>Health Check</th><th>Status</th></tr>'''
    for row in status:
        tab+='<tr>'
        for col in row:
            if col=='GOOD':
                tab+='<td style="background-color: #50C76F">%s</td>' % col
            #F51800
            elif  col=='CONCERNING':
                tab+='<td style="background-color: #F59B00">%s</td>' % col
            elif  col=='BAD':
                tab+='<td style="background-color: #F51800">%s</td>' % col
            else:
                tab+='<td>%s</td>' % col
        tab+='</tr>'
    tab+='</table>'
    tab+='<table> <tr style="background-color: #858483"><th>CapacityTotal</th><th>CapacityUsed</th><th>CapacityRemaining</th> <th> Capacity%</th> <th> VolumeFailuresTotal </th> <th> EstimatedCapacityLostTotal</th> </tr>'
    url = burl['nn_url']
    response = requests.get(url)
    tab+='<tr><td>'+str(response.json()['beans'][0]['CapacityTotalGB']/(1024))+'TB'+'</td>'
    tab+='<td>'+str(response.json()['beans'][0]['CapacityUsedGB']/(1024))+'TB'+'</td>'
    if int(response.json()['beans'][0]['CapacityRemainingGB']/(1024)) > 200:
        tab+='<td style="background-color: #50C76F">'+str(response.json()['beans'][0]['CapacityRemainingGB']/(1024))+'TB'+'</td>'
    else:
        tab+='<td style="background-color: #F51800">'+str(response.json()['beans'][0]['CapacityRemainingGB']/(1024))+'TB'+'</td>'
    per_cent = (response.json()['beans'][0]['CapacityUsedGB'] / response.json()['beans'][0]['CapacityTotalGB'] )*100
    print(per_cent)
    if int(per_cent) < 75 :
        tab+='<td style="background-color: #50C76F"">'+str(per_cent)+'</td>'
    elif int(per_cent) < 85 :
        tab+='<td style="background-color: #F59B00">'+str(per_cent)+'</td>'
    else:
        tab+='<td style="background-color: #F51800">'+str(per_cent)+'</td>'

    if int(response.json()['beans'][0]['VolumeFailuresTotal']) > 0:
        tab+='<td style="background-color: #F51800">'+str(response.json()['beans'][0]['VolumeFailuresTotal'])+'</td>'
    else:
        tab+='<td style="background-color: #50C76F">'+str(response.json()['beans'][0]['VolumeFailuresTotal'])+'</td>'
    tab+='<td>'+str(response.json()['beans'][0]['EstimatedCapacityLostTotal']/(1024*1024*1024*1024))+'TB'+'</td></tr>'
    tab+='</table>'
    ## This works with win32 package in local, need to make changes to work with unix sendmail
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'test@abc.com'
    mail.Subject = burl['name']+' - SOD EMAIL'
    mail.Body = 'SOD TEST'
    mail.HTMLBody = tab #this field is optional
    mail.Send()
```

- The above script works fine from the local machine, where at the end it uses Outlook to send email but what I am trying is to add the below part to the code instead of Outlook to send emails via SMTP. I couldn't able to get the output attached to this thread, when I try to use SMTP.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python

   import smtplib

   sender = 'alerts@abc.com'
   receivers = ['someone@abc.com']
   message = """From: alerts@abc.com
   To: someone@abc.com
   Subject: SMTP e-mail test

   This is a test e-mail message.
   """

   try:
      smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
      smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
      print "Successfully sent email"
   except SMTPException:
      print "Error: unable to send email"
  ```

The second block code is something I have tested, I am able to receive the email when I fire the script from the server through SMTP but, when I try to add this part to the 1st script, I am getting what I have put inside message block (i.e) This is a test e-mail message.

The desire output that I am expecting when I send email via SMTP is that (attached to the thread) but am not getting it.

**Expected output:**
[image: Output]

Thank you!

Comment: not an actual answer, but stuff like [jinja2](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/) exists exactly for scenarios like this. This is a templating engine where you can easily turn a template into proper HTML without much work.

Comment: standard mail sends only plain text - you have to create `multi-part` mail and add `alternative version in HTML` , And it can be simpler if you use standard object `email.message.EmailMessage`

Comment: see Python doc: [email.examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) and search example with `add_alternative()`

Answer (score 0):

Standard mail sends only plain text. You have to create `multi-part` mail and `add alternative` in HTML. And it can be simpler if you use standard object [email.message.EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html).

Something like this:

```
import smtplib
from  email.message import EmailMessage

tab = '<html>text in html</html>'

# --- create ---

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = 'alerts@abc.com'
msg['To']   = 'someone@abc.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'SMTP e-mail test'

msg.set_content("""This is a e-mail message in plain text.""")

msg.add_alternative(tab, subtype='html')  # <-- version in HTML

#print( msg.as_string() )

# --- send ---

try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtpObj.send_message(msg)             # <-- instead of `sendmail()`
    print("Successfully sent email")
except smtplib.SSMTPException:
    print("Error: unable to send email")
```

---

If you use `print( msg.as_string() )` then you may see how it all looks as plain text.

```
From: alerts@abc.com
To: someone@abc.com
Subject: SMTP e-mail test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============0079637904683359957=="

--===============0079637904683359957==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a e-mail message in plain text

--===============0079637904683359957==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0

<html>text in html</html>

--===============0079637904683359957==--
```

---

See more in Python doc: [email examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)